# How to go HTTPS

Tags: https

well i want to learn how to make my site use HTTPS protocol i have read and article about it but wasn't much of help....

what do i need to do more\apart from development to launching (going live) of a normal site...

Comment: You will need to purchase and install an SSL certificate on your web server. Details on how this can be done (more precisely the second part) will of course depend on the web server you are using. As far as the first part is concerned feel free to checkout [google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=purchase+ssl+certificate&aq=0&aqi=g3g-m2&aql=&oq=purchase+SSL+&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=5673716d440c1f33). Also this is not a programming related question and is more adapted to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: It would be useful to know which platform you're using: Apache Httpd, Microsoft IIS, Apache Tomcat or other Java container, something else?

Comment: Which platform/server are you using?  The steps vary for each platform, though the same get/install certificate is the same.

Comment: You don't need to do anything differently in terms of development. The steps to enable https in your web server vary depending on which web server you are using, so please tell us if you are using IIS, Apache or a something else.

Comment: This is something you probably best check with your hosting provider (unless you are hosting the server yourself).

Answer (score 1):

As user heb asnwered, you'll configure your HTTP-server to listen on `TCP port 443` and `buy` a SSL certificate.

Making your http-server to listen on TCP port 443 isn't very difficult. But steps vary across different software, so we won't be able to provide you an accurate answer without knowing your server.

An SSL certificate is used to identify your website and notifies the users whether they're visiting a legitimate site or not.
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x64.html
http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=10694

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure your http-server software (like Apache with mod_ssl or Cherokee) to 1. listen to port 443 (standard HTTPS port) and 2. to provide a valid SSL certificate.

All the SSL stuff is done by these http-servers and is completely independent from applications served by these servers.

See http://www.cherokee-project.com/faq.html for more information about SSL and cherokee or apache.org for apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a hosting provider such as GoDaddy or 1&1, they can usually help you with this.  You will need to purchase an SSL certificate.